# How to solve these warnings when compiling Octave-4.0.0 with JIT enabled?

Tags: compilation, llvm, octave, jit

I tried to compile octave-4.0.0 source with JIT feature. First, I installed LLVM and enabled the JIT feature by configuring:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-jit
```

But, I got these warnings:

```
configure: WARNING: llvm/IR/Verifier.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: llvm/IR/Verifier.h: check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: llvm/IR/Verifier.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: llvm/IR/Verifier.h: section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: llvm/IR/Verifier.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------ ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to http://octave.org/bugs.html ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------ ##
configure: WARNING: Missing LLVM file TargetData.h.  JIT compiler is disabled.
```

To solve the warning of missing LLVM file, I looked into LLVM's header files and found that TargetData.h not exist in `/usr/include/llvm/target`, so I manually copy [the header file](http://legup.eecg.utoronto.ca/doxygen/TargetData_8h-source.html) to the path. However, same warnings showed again when I'm reconfiguring.

Another warning (present but cannot be compiled) is also a problem for me.

Does anyone know how to deal with these two warnings? **(I need to enable jit compiler in Octave)**

P.S. I have tried using LLVM 3.7.0 and LLVM 3.5.0, both these two version don't install TargetData.h into `Your Prefix/include/llvm/Target`.

Comment: Which distribution do you use? And don't expect too much optimization from JIT in Octave. Currently only simple loops do benefit from JIT. You might be better to vectorize the code by hand.